# NLP: Question answer with 2 contexts

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, question-answering

Is there a Hugging Face Transformer that takes 2 contexts as input for question answering? For example, I could have transcript of a meeting in first context and agenda of the meeting in the second context. Then ask a question - Did the meeting adhere to the discussion topics given in the agenda? Alternatively, can you suggest how to solve such types of question answering problems that might require multiple contexts?

Comment: You could always just try and combine the two contexts right?

Comment: yeach I could do that too. But a transformer with 2 separate contexts is a lot cleaner IMHO.